# Relational Databases One-to-One realationship with partial participation on both sides

Tags: database, mapping, entity-relationship

How can I map two entities for example Patients and Account 
Such that:

- Not every account belongs to a patient
- Not every patient has an account

Answer (score 0):

Just create the relationship as a separate table:

```
Patient_Accounts (PatientID PK, AccountID UQ)
```

It doesn't matter which one you choose as PK and which as UQ, it's the same thing really. Participation is optional since you don't have to insert records for Patients/Accounts which aren't related.